# Run 2 or more applications inside our third android based application

Tags: android

I want to executive/run other pre-installed android based application inside my new developed application. For example I want to run what's app, Facebook, and Skype at the same time within my application.
I am analyzing about the android containers in which application can be load and execute. Like we used WebView container  to load website.

Please suggest for the same

Comment: It's totally possible. I don't know why you say it's not. Also, your question needs more details. What have you tried thus far? Show us your code. What is actually blocking you?

Comment: If it is possible then please tell me which android container are used to run the application in our applicaton which we are developing. e.g. lets suppose I want to run two application(whatsapp, facebook) in our apllication which we are developing at a time. @Stephan

Comment: Please edit your question and insert that information in there. Since Facebook and Whatsapp are not your applications, it's going to be much trickier. Also, please tell us the underlying reason why you want to do this? Maybe there is another way to get what you want.

Comment: I want to run what's app, Facebook, and Skype at the same time within my application. @Stephan

Comment: You're approaching that problem incorrectly. Use their APIs and code your own solution. https://www.skype.com/en/developer/ https://developers.facebook.com/ https://www.whatsapp.com/business/api/?lang=en

Answer (score 0):

You should use **Deep Links** or *better* **Dynamic Links** - https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android/receive

How it works? You have 2 buttons in your App. On click on them you will open needed app or open it page on Play Market (or your own web site or something else, because you can config it via Dynamic Links).